# Is the new review section promoting bad edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, review

Yesterday while I was [editing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8482258/revisions), somebody else edited before I did.

It was a minor code formatting change, while there were **plenty of other possible improvements** as well. This isn't the first time I encountered this behavior. My guess is this is because of the Reviewer badge.

At least for this user that seems to be the reason; just check out [his recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738746/gurung?tab=activity). There seem to be plenty of other small 2-10 characters non-commented edits.

I see the following problems with this:

- These minor edits count towards the Reviewer badge of the first user which edits, without guaranteeing they are good edits. Unlike quickly answering questions and later expanding on them ([fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/157047)), there is no reason for users to do a more thorough edit at a later point.
- Subsequent edits aren't rewarded. So people mainly motivated by reviewing won't be motivated to edit all the remaining mistakes in the post any more.

Is this a problem that should be addressed? If so, how?

Comment: I still see this as a big problem. I encounter users who have over a hundred *awful edits* which have been suggested and accepted.

Answer (score 7):

> Subsequent edits aren't rewarded. So people mainly motivated by reviewing won't be motivated to edit all the remaining mistakes in the post any more.

Doesn't that only apply to subsequent edits *by the same person* to that post?  You should still gain reputation (if you're eligible) and badges for suggesting an improved edit to the same post yourself.

---

In the case of someone making suggested edits:

If they're making small edits to posts that can be improved substantially, you can either improve upon their edit or vote to reject it (depending on your reputation) as **too minor**.  See the following section from [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/1288)

> **What about abuse?**
>
> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.

Comment: That's great...[but reviewers *tend* to accept those minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112275/rising-number-of-invalid-minor-edits).

Comment: This particular user has editing privileges, so unless I am missing something suggested edits aren't relevant? I can only do a rollback, and that doesn't seem productive either.

Comment: @Bobby, I'm suggesting we reverse that tendency.  Or if not reverse it (by rejecting too minor edits outright) at least stop it by improving those edits instead of accepting them.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I was the one who was missing something.  See my edits.  Rolling back probably isn't that productive, but improving the post by further editing is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: _"You should still gain reputation (if you're eligible) and badges for suggesting an improved edit to the same post yourself."_ Doesn't only the first edit count towards the Reviewing badge? Further edits could of course still count towards other badges.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I thought it was only one edit per post per person, so I can't just keep modifying the same post to get closer to the badge.  I think if you come in after me and review the same post you should still get credit.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That would be good, and resolve this discussion for me (at least the best way how to handle it)! Could you confirm that? Otherwise I'll check next time it happens. It might still be worthwhile to find out a way to demotivate people doing small edits just to obtain the badge quicker.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I've been trying to think of a way to test this, but I'm coming up empty.  If I link to a post that I've reviewed and  you go to it from that link, I know you won't get review cred.  You have to do it from the /review page.  We might have to ask for clarification from a dev.